# Java create URL to arabic filename

Tags: java, parsing, url, utf-8, uri

How can I generate a url which every browser understands, even when I have to deal with arabic/chinese/... filenames?

e.g.

http://someserver.com/files/somehash/لوحة المفاتيح العربية.jpg

I also need to download these files and store them with their original name on the file system; do I have to rename it manually or does the downloadstream handle this for me (I have to connect with a ASCII string to the server so that he understands the filename)...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java URL encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding)

Comment: Try `URLEncoder` & `URLDecoder`.

Comment: best way is to encode the filename and write a handler to decode the filename, rest your handler can take care of.

Comment: are there any documented best practices for those handlers? I haven't worked with any yet..

Answer (score 0):

filename should match both in your url and the file system unless you have a middleware service logic.

Encoding the URL using encode and appropriate encoding should help the browsers. 
Check [URLEncoder.encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String))

Comment: so you prefer REAL_FILENAME = STORED_FILENAME? 
am I not getting any problems with ftp-encoding restrictions?
Isn't it better to store it with a "safe" name and save the real name in a DB?